# Locking orientation to portrait force close in my phone

Tags: android, android-orientation

I want my app to lock into portrait mode. For this I used this code :

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                  >
```

and in MyActivity class :

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

This code work correctly in emulator, but when I install and run in my phone, the app is force closed.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: logcat logs ... let me guess StackOverflow hehehe

Comment: @Selvin : I said "This code work correctly in emulator, but when I install and run in my phone, the app is force closed".

Comment: and i said: "logcat logs" (from phone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo already use in manifest then there is no need to use by pragmatically. So remove the `onConfigurationChanged` method from your code.

Comment: what happened better to put your loagcat

Answer (score 1):

I am using

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

in the manifest file, no other code in Java side and is working.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here:

- Remove `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` from manifest
- Remove `onConfigurationChanged` from java

  and it should work just fine